# Add horizontal views (line) between menu items xml

Tags: android, xml, navigationview, android-navigationview

I'm using Navigation View, tags menu and items, I would like to add lines between every option item. Here is my menu:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>
```

I don't know well how this item works and why we can not put other classes of tags from XML.

Comment: Wait... *Horizontal* line? You mean like line between every record of the Menu popup?

Comment: exactly It's what I need

Answer (score 7):

You have to group the items you want to separate with lines. **Every group need a unique id**.

```
<group android:id="@+id/group1"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:title="First item" />
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/group2"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:title="Second item" />
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/group3"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:title="Third item" />
</group>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@kulosos answer only works with drawerNavigator, as shown in the snapshot.

For menu item, try this:

```
<menu>
    <group android:id="@+id/group1" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Import"
            android:title="@string/Import"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/Gallery"
            android:title="@string/Gallery"/>
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/group2">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Add `MenuCompat.setGroupDividerEnabled(menu, true)` in `onCreateOptionsMenu` to make group working.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    MenuCompat.setGroupDividerEnabled(menu, true);
    return true;
}
```